# Update a record instead of inserting if where with big associative array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a big associative array like that:

```
$ar = [
    "column_name" => "column_value"
]
```

I need to check the existance of a record before inserting it. If the record exists I should update id.

I tried with this:

```
$rec = MyModel::where($ar)->first();
If ($rec === null) {
    // the record does not exist => insert it
} else {
    // the record does exist => update it
}
```

It does not work. The record (even if I create the array with the same values) is always inserted

Comment: What does `$ar` have?

Answer (score 2):

You can use updateOrCreate method: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: It does not work. It inserts another record, and if I check the fields of the records, they are the same

Comment: The code is that I wrote on the question. MyModel::updateOrCreate($associativeArray);

Answer (score 1):

You may use Eloquent `updateOrCreate` method:

```php
$rec = MyModel::updateOrCreate($ar);
```

Check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#other-creation-methods) for more info;

Comment: It does not work. It inserts another record, and if I check the fields of the records, they are the same

Comment: @GiacomoM it means you have a condition on you where clause (your `$ar`) that is always false.